# Show rows in MySQL table where another row does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in my MySQL database which has columns:

- callid
- event

I want to select all rows where the event is 'ENTERQUEUE':

```
SELECT count(*) AS avg_hold_time
FROM ast_queue_log
WHERE queuename = '0536*401'
  AND DATE(time) = '2014-03-07'
  AND event = 'ENTERQUEUE'
ORDER BY time DESC;
```

But then I want to show all the other rows where the 'callid' is equal the result from the above query (for each row returned in the above query) **AND** there is no row where the event equals 'CONNECT'.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery with the `NOT EXISTS` operator:

```
SELECT   AVG(arg1) AS avg_hold_time 
FROM     ast_queue_log aql
WHERE    queuename = '0536*401' AND
         DATE(time) = '2014-03-07' AND
         event = 'ENTERQUEUE' AND
         NOT EXISTS (SELECT cnt.callid
                     FROM   ast_queueu_log cnt
                     WHERE  -- Same conditions as the surrounding query
                            queuename = '0536*401' AND
                            DATE(time) = '2014-03-07' AND
                            event = 'CONNECT' AND
                            -- matching callids
                            cnt.callid = aql.callid)
ORDER BY time DESC
```

Comment: @MarcusAdams agreed, that was poor wording on my behalf. Thanks for the feedback - I amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake in my code. i do not need to select average, i need to select the number of rows

Comment: @user3223205 just replace `avg(arg1)` with `count(*)`

Comment: i seem to be getting a count of 10 returned but i know this it not correct

Comment: basically, when a phone call comes in it creates a row in the database with an event of 'ENTERQUEUE' then when the call is answered by an agent it inserts a row with the same callid and an event of 'CONNECT' so i want to show all the calls that do not have a row with even 'CONNECT'

Answer (score 1):

This is generally solved with a self-join in the form of an anti-join:

```
SELECT avg(aql1.arg1) AS avg_hold_time
FROM ast_queue_log aql1
// Left outer join on other records with 'CONNECT' event for same callid
LEFT JOIN ast_queue_log aql2
ON aql1.callid = aql2.callid AND aql2.event = 'CONNECT'
WHERE aql1.queuename = '0536*401'
  AND DATE(aql1.time) = '2014-03-07'
  AND aql1.event = 'ENTERQUEUE'
  // Then only include those records that didn't successfully join
  AND aql2.callid IS NULL
ORDER BY aql1.time DESC;
```

Maybe you need to throw some other conditions on the JOIN, such as a 'CONNECT' event with the same queuename and date, but you haven't specified.

Comment: i get column time is ambiguous

Comment: @user3223205, sorry, forgot to add the table alias prefix to `time` in the `ORDER BY` clause. Fixed.